# Is this question 你明天想做什么 correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to ask: What do you want to do tomorrow? Is the following question correct?

```
你明天想做什么
```

I doubt where to put `明天` in the sentence and the use of `做` because several other characters can also mean `do`.

Comment: In the normal sentence, the time is usually on the second place, right after the subject. In English, we usually place the time on the first or last place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 你明天想做什么？

Correct!

Also correct: 你明天想要干什么？

Comment: Yes `干` also means `do`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

yes,it’s correct. Also “明天你想做什么”

Comment: Yes I also though about placing `明天` at the beginning of the sentence, but I was not sure if it is correct. Now I know it. Thanks